# Find source of print call

Tags: java, debugging

I'm debugging a Java application that helpfully prints this to the console about a dozen times during startup:

```
java.awt.Dimension[width=140,height=122]
```

I want to shut it up but I have no idea where it's coming from. The application is huge and I don't know much about it. I can probably find the culprit by stepping through the code as it runs but I'm wondering is there a cleverer way?

Answer (score 8):

I found my offending print statement (inside a getPreferredSize() method), but I also found a more general solution. By replacing `System.out` using [`System.setOut`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29) it's possible, in theory, to catch a print statement when it happens.

This isn't fully reliable as: (1) class [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) has many printing methods for different data types and there isn't a good single method to override. The methods that do the real output are private. (2) If it wanted to, code could split a message up into individual characters, so there would be no easy way to do the `String.contains()` check.

Still, as a quick debugging hack, this seems to work nicely:

```
System.setOut(new java.io.PrintStream(
        new java.io.FileOutputStream(java.io.FileDescriptor.out)) {
    @Override
    public void print(String s) {
        super.print(s);
        if (s.contains("java.awt.Dimension")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Found you!");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You must be printing the object of `Dimension` class in your code somewhere. What you see as output:

```
java.awt.Dimension[width=140,height=122]
```

comes when `toString` method of `Dimension` class will be called. Here is the source of `toString` from `Dimension` class:

```
   public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "[width=" + width + ",height=" + height + "]";
    }
```

So look for `Dimension` class objects in your code, especially in `System.out.println`.